# Play video using XBMC in raspbmc displays OpenGLSpectrum instead of video

Tags: video, kodi, display

As question mentioned, when I try play a video in XBMC (my distro is: raspbmc), it play sound and display OpenGL Spectrum instead of display video content !

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I also had this problem for a week and I finally fixed it by increasing the GPU RAM to 128 (from 64).

Answer (score 1):

you may try different distributions, [GeexBox](http://download.geexbox.org/snapshots/geexbox-xbmc-bcm2708-raspberrypi/), [OpenELEC](http://www.openelec.tv/get-openelec/download/viewdownload/10/109), [XBian](http://xbian.org/download/) to see how it works for you, if all they behave similar way, probably there's something wrong with your board, though it's very unlikely.

i'd recommend to start from OpenELEC.

Comment: I didn't try any distributions except Raspbmc. I wonder if my LCD cause this problem or not, because when I plug my TV directly through HDMI port, it worked well!

Comment: I have just tried to install OpenElec. But CPU Usage is too high. And now I move back to raspbmc :(

Comment: was your video playing well, or still OpenGL Spectrum Display?

Comment: It notices that the video is being played, I just can't see the video on screen, btw I can listen to its audio .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a codec issue to me. The same kind of thing would happen using windows whilst trying to play a video file for which the correct video codec wasn't installed. You would get the spectrum display, but still hear the audio.

not entirely sure if raspbmc has ffmpeg installed by default, but you could always try SSHing into your pi, and running the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.flv(/mpg/mp4/avi)
```

this should give you some codec information that the video file has been encoded with, you can google whether the pi can play it, or update your question with the information.